# Suppress "The controller for path '/' was not found or does not implement IController." Server-Side with Application Insights

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights

I am aware of this discussion (with no exception-source-side resolution): https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cb944fc4-4410-4e49-ba0b-43e675fe2173/ignoring-certain-exeptions-not-implementing-icontroller-bad-url?forum=ApplicationInsights

I have the same problem in that I don't want to pollute my exception log with traffic generated by bots (we only have Web API controllers). I was able to ignore those for server requests (usually showing in "Failed Requests") using a telemetry processor and simply return'ing on 404.

However, wasn't able to get rid of the exception entries - does anyone know of a setting / filter / you-name-it that would allow me to decide server-side  (before they are sent off) which exceptions are delivered to Application Insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to implement a custom `ITelemetryProcessor` as outlined here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#filtering

```cs
public class ControllerNotImplementedTelemetryProcessor : ITelemetryProcessor
{
    private ITelemetryProcessor Next { get; }

    public void Process(ITelemetry item)
    {
        var exception = item as ExceptionTelemetry;

        if (exception != null && exception.Exception.GetType() == typeof(HttpException) && exception.Exception.Message.Contains("was not found or does not implement IController"))
            return;

        Next.Process(item);
    }

    public ControllerNotImplementedTelemetryProcessor(ITelemetryProcessor next)
    {
        Next = next;
    }
}
```

Registering the custom processor happens in Global.ascx:

```cs
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder
    .Use(next => new ControllerNotImplementedTelemetryProcessor(next))
    .Build();
```

Note that this is obviously  a very crude filter, depending on the language of the error message to be English might be acceptable but could also cause false positives.